# How to zip file using "ZipArchive library" in iphone ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to implement [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/list) in my project.

Using this library I want to archive files like images into zip file.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try my code
Zipcode :

```
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* dPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* txtfile = [dPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.txt"];
    NSString* zipfile = [dPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.zip"];
    ZipArchive* zip = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
    BOOL ret = [zip CreateZipFile2:zipfile];
    ret = [zip addFileToZip:txtfile newname:@"test.txt"];//zip
    if( ![zip CloseZipFile2] )
    {
        zipfile = @"";
    }
    [zip release];
    NSLog(@"The file has been zipped");
```

Unzipcode:

```
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* dPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString* zipfile = [dPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.zip"] ;
    NSString* unzipto = [dPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test"] ;
    ZipArchive* zip = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
    if([zip UnzipOpenFile:zipfile] )
    {
        BOOL ret = [zip UnzipFileTo:unzipto overWrite:YES];
        if(NO == ret)
        {
        }
        [zip UnzipCloseFile];
    }
    [zip release];
    NSLog(@"The file has been unzipped");
```

Comment: how to check this zip file ?

Comment: What does the import statement look like?

Answer (score 2):

This code will work perfectly to zip a file.

```
ZipArchive *zip = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
if(![zip UnzipOpenFile:fileToZipPath]) {
//open file is there

            if ([zip CreateZipFile2:newZipFilePath overWrite:YES]) {

                //zipped successfully

                NSLog(@"Archive zip Success");

            } 

        } else  {

            NSLog(@"Failure To Zip Archive");

        }
      }
```

To unzip,

```
if([zip UnzipOpenFile:zipFilePath]) {

            //zip file is there

            if ([zip UnzipFileTo:newFilePath overWrite:YES]) {

                //unzipped successfully

                NSLog(@"Archive unzip Success");

                zipOpened = YES;

            } 

        } else  {

            NSLog(@"Failure To Open Archive");

        }
```

Comment: @Develoepr : thanks for replying... But I am unable to find `zip CreateZipFile2:newZipFilePath overWrite:YES` method. There is only method `CreateZipFile2` and also tried this but I did not find any zip file at given document directory path. What should I do ?

Comment: Where are you keeping your files?